# SharePoint 2013 - Unable to create Folders

Tags: 2013, migration, folder

We are in process of migrating from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. We have come across an issue in our UAT environment with creating New Folders in document libraries. Some more information below:

1. When I go to a document library(any type of library), click on "New Folder" in ribbon, enter the name of folder and click Save button in the pop up frame, nothing happens i.e. the form posts back, the pop up frame refreshes and the folder name input field becomes blank again. There are no errors reported - either on SharePoint UI or when trying to debug javascript in browser.
2. I have tried in different versions of IE, Chrome and Firefox but the issue persists everywhere.
3. The above behaviour is seen only in sites with SP2013 UI. The sites that we migrated from SP2010 and are still in 2010 UI do not have this problem. If we upgrade the 2010 sites to 2013 or create new 2013 sites, they get this folder creation problem.
4. I am the site collection and farm administrator. There are definitely no permission issues as I am able to create folders using explorer view or via SharePoint Designer.
5. The library has folder creation enabled.
6. The problem is not present in our dev environment running on same SP2013 SP1 and CU Sep 2014.
7. I have compared the library's Upload.aspx file from my working DEV environment to problematic UAT environment, but both are the same.

I have tried several solutions related to this problem but did not have any luck as none of those problems were similar to mine (I do not get any error message). Has anyone encountered this issue before ?

All suggestions are welcome.

ULS Logs below:

```
05/14/2015 10:59:32.81  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x32C8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Request 

(GET:http://sitename:80/sites/SP2013/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?ListId=%7B3EC9EF98%2D2EB8%2D4B6F%2D878E%2D7CCD813A448C%7D&PageType=8&RootFolder=%2Fsites

%2FSP2013%2FShared%20Documents&Type=1&IsDlg=1)). Parent No      
05/14/2015 10:59:32.81  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x32C8  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request 

(GET:http://sitename:80/sites/SP2013/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?ListId=%7B3EC9EF98%2D2EB8%2D4B6F%2D878E%2D7CCD813A448C%7D&PageType=8&RootFolder=%2Fsites

%2FSP2013%2FShared%20Documents&Type=1&IsDlg=1)  a340069d-eeac-7001-ae84-2ecd4e73312e    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.82  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x32C8  SharePoint Foundation   Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium  Non-OAuth request. 

IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|DOMAIN\ak542k, ClaimsCount=67   a340069d-eeac-7001-ae84-2ecd4e73312e    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.83  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x32C8  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/sites/SP2013  

a340069d-eeac-7001-ae84-2ecd4e73312e    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.88  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x32C8  SharePoint Foundation   Database    ahjqp   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 

05/14/2015 10:59:32.86, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.137168271386447 for Data Source=SSSQLE2013UAT;Initial 

Catalog=DATABASENAME;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect 

Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint[w3wp][4][SharePoint2013UAT_CWaC_Teams_Content_3] a340069d-eeac-7001-ae84-2ecd4e73312e    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.88  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x32C8  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    UserAgent not available, file operations may not be 

optimized.
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean 

disposeIlb) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo& fileInfo, SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid databaseId, SqlSession session, 

SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[] metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& 

dbres...    a340069d-eeac-7001-ae84-2ecd4e73312e    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.88* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x32C8  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ...) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, 

String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& 

pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& 

pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, 

String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& 

piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, ... a340069d-eeac-7001-ae84-2ecd4e73312e    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.88* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x32C8  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ...Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& 

pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, 

String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& 

pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& 

pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, 

String& pbst... a340069d-eeac-7001-ae84-2ecd4e73312e    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.88* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x32C8  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ...rRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& 

pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, 

UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String 

bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& 

pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& 

pdwVersion,...  a340069d-eeac-7001-ae84-2ecd4e73312e    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.88* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x32C8  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ... String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& 

pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, 

Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& 

pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& 

pgDocScopeId) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebPartPageContent(Uri pageUrl, Int32 pageVersion, PageView requestedView, HttpContext context, Boolean forRender, 

Boolean includeHidden, Boolean mainFileRequest, Boolean fetchDependencyInformation, Boolean& ghostedPage, String& siteRoot, Guid& siteId, Int64& bytes, ... 

a340069d-eeac-7001-ae84-2ecd4e73312e    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.88* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x32C8  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ...Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& 

timeLastModified, Byte& level, Object& buildDependencySetData, UInt32& dependencyCount, Object& buildDependencies, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& 

initialState, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& redirectUrl, Boolean& ObjectIsList, Guid& listId) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformationForInit(HttpContext context, SPWeb spweb, Boolean 

mainFileRequest, String path, Boolean impersonate, Boolean& isAppWeb, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, 

SPFileLevel& spLevel, String& masterPageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl, String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData, 

SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, ...  a340069d-eeac-7001-ae84-2ecd4e73312e    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.88* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x32C8  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ...String& siteRoot, String& redirectUrl, Object& 

oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath) 
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean 

allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithN...  a340069d-eeac-7001-ae84-2ecd4e73312e    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.88* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x32C8  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ...oAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath 

virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean 

allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
    at System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection) 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage() 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean in...  a340069d-eeac-7001-ae84-2ecd4e73312e    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.88* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x32C8  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ...cludeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean 

includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb) 
    at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeReque...   a340069d-eeac-7001-ae84-

2ecd4e73312e    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.88* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x32C8  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ...stContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 

flags) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 

flags) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 

flags)  a340069d-eeac-7001-ae84-2ecd4e73312e    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.88  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x32C8  SharePoint Foundation   Files   aiv4w   Medium  Spent 0 ms to bind 29798 byte file stream   

a340069d-eeac-7001-ae84-2ecd4e73312e    

05/14/2015 10:59:32.90  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x32C8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request 

(GET:http://sitename:80/sites/SP2013/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?ListId=%7B3EC9EF98%2D2EB8%2D4B6F%2D878E%2D7CCD813A448C%7D&PageType=8&RootFolder=%2Fsites

%2FSP2013%2FShared%20Documents&Type=1&IsDlg=1)). Execution Time=89.4483796124926    a340069d-eeac-7001-ae84-2ecd4e73312e    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.91  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x2EC4  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Request 

(GET:http://sitename:80/sites/SP2013/Shared%20Documents/Forms/Upload.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FSP2013%2FShared%20Documents&Type=1&IsDlg=1)). Parent No 


05/14/2015 10:59:32.91  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x2EC4  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request 

(GET:http://sitename:80/sites/SP2013/Shared%20Documents/Forms/Upload.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FSP2013%2FShared%20Documents&Type=1&IsDlg=1) a340069d-

5eb3-7001-ae84-2206844c6537 
05/14/2015 10:59:32.92  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x2EC4  SharePoint Foundation   Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium  Non-OAuth request. 

IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|DOMAIN\ak542k, ClaimsCount=67   a340069d-5eb3-7001-ae84-2206844c6537    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.95  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x2EC4  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    UserAgent not available, file operations may not be 

optimized.
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean 

disposeIlb) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo& fileInfo, SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid databaseId, SqlSession session, 

SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[] metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& 

dbres...    a340069d-5eb3-7001-ae84-2206844c6537    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.95* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x2EC4  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ...) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, 

String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& 

pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& 

pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, 

String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& 

piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, ... a340069d-5eb3-7001-ae84-2206844c6537    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.95* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x2EC4  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ...Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& 

pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, 

String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& 

pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& 

pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, 

String& pbst... a340069d-5eb3-7001-ae84-2206844c6537    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.95* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x2EC4  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ...rRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& 

pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, 

UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String 

bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& 

pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& 

pdwVersion,...  a340069d-5eb3-7001-ae84-2206844c6537    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.95* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x2EC4  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ... String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& 

pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, 

Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& 

pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& 

pgDocScopeId) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebPartPageContent(Uri pageUrl, Int32 pageVersion, PageView requestedView, HttpContext context, Boolean forRender, 

Boolean includeHidden, Boolean mainFileRequest, Boolean fetchDependencyInformation, Boolean& ghostedPage, String& siteRoot, Guid& siteId, Int64& bytes, ... 

a340069d-5eb3-7001-ae84-2206844c6537    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.95* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x2EC4  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ...Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& 

timeLastModified, Byte& level, Object& buildDependencySetData, UInt32& dependencyCount, Object& buildDependencies, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& 

initialState, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& redirectUrl, Boolean& ObjectIsList, Guid& listId) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformationForInit(HttpContext context, SPWeb spweb, Boolean 

mainFileRequest, String path, Boolean impersonate, Boolean& isAppWeb, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, 

SPFileLevel& spLevel, String& masterPageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl, String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData, 

SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, ...  a340069d-5eb3-7001-ae84-2206844c6537    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.95* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x2EC4  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ...String& siteRoot, String& redirectUrl, Object& 

oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetFileForRequest(HttpContext context, SPWeb web, Boolean exclusion, String virtualPath) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.InitContextWeb(HttpContext context, SPWeb web) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext context) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.GetContextWeb(HttpContext context) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PostResolveRequestCacheHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea) 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IEx...  a340069d-5eb3-7001-ae84-2206844c6537    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.95* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x2EC4  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ...ecutionStep.Execute() 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb) 
    at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 

flags) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 

flags) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompl...  a340069d-5eb3-7001-ae84-2206844c6537    
05/14/2015 10:59:32.95* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x2EC4  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ...etion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& 

notificationStatus) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 

flags) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 

flags)  a340069d-5eb3-7001-ae84-2206844c6537    

05/14/2015 10:59:33.04  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x2EC4  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request 

(GET:http://sitename:80/sites/SP2013/Shared%20Documents/Forms/Upload.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FSP2013%2FShared%20Documents&Type=1&IsDlg=1)). Execution 

Time=125.860688998183   a340069d-5eb3-7001-ae84-2206844c6537    

05/14/2015 10:59:33.13  w3wp.exe (0x0BD4)   0x4940  SharePoint Foundation   Micro Trace uls4    Medium  Micro Trace Tags: (none)        

05/14/2015 10:59:34.83  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x4B68  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Request 

(POST:http://sitename:80/sites/SP2013/Shared%20Documents/Forms/Upload.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FSP2013%2FShared%20Documents&Type=1&IsDlg=1)). Parent No    


05/14/2015 10:59:34.83  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x4B68  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request 

(POST:http://sitename:80/sites/SP2013/Shared%20Documents/Forms/Upload.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FSP2013%2FShared%20Documents&Type=1&IsDlg=1)    a440069d-

1e2b-7001-ae84-2edfd1e69ab4 
05/14/2015 10:59:34.83  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x4B68  SharePoint Foundation   Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium  Non-OAuth request. 

IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|DOMAIN\ak542k, ClaimsCount=67   a440069d-1e2b-7001-ae84-2edfd1e69ab4    
05/14/2015 10:59:34.88  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x4B68  SharePoint Foundation   Database    ahjqp   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 

05/14/2015 10:59:34.84, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.136609541156767 for Data Source=SSSQLE2013UAT;Initial 

Catalog=;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint


05/14/2015 10:59:34.89* w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x4B68  SharePoint Foundation   Files   ak8dj   High    ...etion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& 

notificationStatus) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 

flags) 
    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 

flags)  a440069d-1e2b-7001-ae84-2edfd1e69ab4    
05/14/2015 10:59:34.89  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x4B68  SharePoint Foundation   Files   aiv4w   Medium  Spent 0 ms to bind 5911 byte file stream    

a440069d-1e2b-7001-ae84-2edfd1e69ab4    
05/14/2015 10:59:34.89  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x4B68  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/sites/SP2013  

a440069d-1e2b-7001-ae84-2edfd1e69ab4    

05/14/2015 10:59:34.94  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x4B68  SharePoint Foundation   General af4yd   High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] 

TenantAppEtag record requested but there is no sitesubscription or tenantId for site {0} so we will use the WebApp Id for the cache.    a440069d-1e2b-7001-

ae84-2edfd1e69ab4   
05/14/2015 10:59:34.97  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x4B68  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dn4s    High    FetchDataFromURL start at(outside if): 1 

param: start    a440069d-1e2b-7001-ae84-2edfd1e69ab4    
05/14/2015 10:59:34.98  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x4B68  SharePoint Foundation   Micro Trace uls4    Medium  Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,6 agb9s,50 ak8dj,4 

b4ly,83 dn4s    a440069d-1e2b-7001-ae84-2edfd1e69ab4    
05/14/2015 10:59:34.98  w3wp.exe (0x3C08)   0x4B68  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request 

(POST:http://sitename:80/sites/SP2013/Shared%20Documents/Forms/Upload.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FSP2013%2FShared%20Documents&Type=1&IsDlg=1)). Execution 

Time=152.916781322766   a440069d-1e2b-7001-ae84-2edfd1e69ab4    
05/14/2015 10:59:35.50  w3wp.exe (0x2BE8)   0x4504  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dka1    High    

SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetUpdatedQueryParameterSpecifications--Proxy Name:Search Service EastApplicationProxy EndPoint: http://ps-specasch-

uat:32843/83500ec3ab724696bc872e301be7f13a/SearchService.svc        
05/14/2015 10:59:35.50  w3wp.exe (0x2BE8)   0x4504  SharePoint Server Search    Query   dk8z    High    SearchServiceApplicationProxy::GetChannel--

Channel Creation time: 0.9958
```

Thanks in anticipation!
Regards,
Raj

Comment: Whats the message in the log.If the list is using content type make sure they are working correctly, there is an issue with the content type of the list.

Comment: Raj, did you check the SharePoint logs to see if there were any errors?

Comment: Just added to my questions above - nothing I can relate this problem to.

Comment: Meanwhile, can you do one more check, if you have chrome browser then open console and make sure you preserve the logs while navigation and perform the action, it will display if you have any problem with core js files

Comment: If you try to add a folder using Windows Explorer view, what happens?

Comment: @Mike - The folder gets created via explorer view (and SP designer) and when you come back to the browser and refresh, the folder is there.

Comment: Do you have any customized pages using css or javascript/jquery?

Comment: @Mike - No nothing. When I create a brand new out-of-box team site, it doesn't work there either.

Comment: Do you still have this issue? Did you check the folder creation from different PC with different user?

Comment: I would try to see if there is a custom masterpage still present that is preventing it... Also, try to create a new site collection and test there. Seems like the masterpage is still present that may be causing problems from the migration

Answer (score -1):

You have to show the column "Type" in your view to see your folders in a library.